# How do I crop a DXF file in Mathematica?

Tags: image3d, 3d-printing

I need to make DXF files at a certain size and crop ratio.  How can this be done in Mathematica?  There is nothing in the docs that show it can be done.  So I have no "starting point"  In my application DXF files need to be made the same size as other objects without scaling them.

```
Import["ExampleData/seashell.dxf"]
```

[Here's an example of 3D cropping being done in Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/340963-how-can-i-cut-crop-patch-3d-stl-file-object)

Comment: Show an example, give us more details, specify the "certain" size and crop ratio, show some code... the usual.

Comment: I have not found anything in the documentation that allows for cropping a dxf file so I have no starting point here.

Comment: I’ve not tried this with a DXF, but to crop ListContour plots (so as to avoid unwanted effects around the periphery of the convex hull) I’ve defined a rectangular region with a hole in it - in this case I guess the hole would effectively correspond to AutoCad’s concept of a viewport.  If you colour the region white (or whatever other colour you might prefer) and draw it on top of the DXF then I think you’ll get the effect you’re looking for.  As this might well be something I’ll need to do at some point, I’d be interested to know how you eventually solve the problem.

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with DXF?  Or is this actually a question about `MeshRegion`s?  If this was an STL would you know what to do?

Comment: @chuy I have no experience with STL files and have DXF files provided for this project.

Comment: Note: I am not cropping an Image in a DXF file as the title of this question was edited to reflect.  I have DXF files that must be cropped.

Comment: @RHall Put yourself in our shoes though: where would we start? I have no DXF files on hand to play with, so I would have to create one, play around with it, etc. and then probably discover that yours was different in subtle but meaningful ways that mean that all effort is wasted. This is YOUR problem: you should provide e.g. a sample file and precise specifications of where you want it cropped. I understand that the docs are silent on this, but surely that does not mean that you cannot try anything on your own! How would anybody else here solve your problem then, if that was the case?

Comment: @MarcoB I asked this question because it does generically apply to anyone wishing to crop a DXF file.   It would be conjecture to assume the DXF file specification allows for potential differences in DXF files that would break them for different applications.  I hear that you believe that my question should not be here in this format, and see the downvotes, but do see there is a broad application for an answer, and respectfully disagree with the premise that in all cases code must be posted or files provided.  The question is clear and basic enough to not require either.

Comment: Maybe you can show us someone "cropping a DXF file" (which I don't think really makes sense) using another programming language?

Comment: @chuy Good Idea, I've edited the question to show that.  Thank you!

Comment: @chuy That was indeed a great idea.

Comment: Again this really doesn't have anything to do with DXF as a file format, but rather MeshRegion you get from importing one.

Comment: @chuy True, but it solves the problem of having too much of the mesh region for certain applications.  This is common for some models and is important when using 3D and 2D items that must have proportional relationships held when exporting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit hacky but it seems to work; it uses the `PlotRange` option of the `Show` command along with `DiscretizeGraphics`.

Creating a DXF file.

```
Export["a.dxf", ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Triceratops"}, "MeshRegion"]]
```

Loading, cropping, exporting:

```
R = Import["a.dxf"];
S = DiscretizeRegion@DiscretizeGraphics[
   Show[
    R,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}
    ]
   ]
Export["b.dxf", S]
```

[image]

To those of you who wonder why I use both `DiscretizeRegion` and `DiscretizeGraphics`: `DiscretizeGraphics` does not generate pure triangle meshes which is bad because they either exported or imported incorrectly. `DiscretizeRegion` splits polygons to generate pure triangle meshes.

## Edit

As Chip Hurst pointed out in a comment the following does the same in an easier way:

```
DiscretizeRegion[R, {{0, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}]
```

Moreover, it is about 10 times as fast.

Comment: @HeinrikSchumacher  Nicely done!  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: `ClipPlanes` might also be useful.

Comment: Another very good method!  Thanks, @chuy!

Comment: We can skip `DiscretizeGraphics` with `DiscretizeRegion[R, {{0, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}]`.